# React Router version issue

Tags: reactjs, django, routes, react-router

I just had a quick question about a React project I'm working on. I'm trying to get React Router to route to both a login page and, upon successfully doing that, have it re-route to my app's homepage. However, I'm using version 6, and I keep getting the following error when I try to run it:

"[PrivateRoute] is not a  component. All component children of  must be a  or <React.Fragment>"

Any insight into how I can reformat my code? Thanks!!

```
import React from 'react';
  import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
  import Login from './Login';
  import Spreadsheetester from './Spreadsheet';
  
  const PrivateRoute = ({ element: Element, ...rest}) => (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      element={
        localStorage.getItem('token') ? (
          <Element />
        ) : (
          <Navigate to="/login" replace />
        )
      }
    />
  );
  
  const App = () => {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/login" element={<Login />} />
          <PrivateRoute exact path="/" element={<Spreadsheet />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    );
  };
  
  export default App;
```